# Форматирование jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

Есть код:

```js
export const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div className="div" id="div" onClick={() => {}} onKeyDown={() => {}} onBlur={() => {}}>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

После форматирования prettier`ом выглядит так:

```js
<div
  className="div"
  id="div"
  onClick={() => {}}
  onKeyDown={() => {}}
  onBlur={() => {}}>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы было так:

```js
<div
  className="div"
  id="div"
  onClick={() => {}}
  onKeyDown={() => {}}
  onBlur={() => {}}
>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Есть какие-то настройки того же prettier`а или другой плагин ?

Comment: Для более гибкой настройки синтаксиса кода используйте ESLint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": false,
```